# Using ffmpeg in a script to detect and fix mp3 with sample rate != 44.1k

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, mp3

I only want to touch files that aren't 44.1 (as `mp3` is lossy, so `re-encoding/resampling` files that dont needed to be touched is t good)

I have started playing with ffprobe (assuming this is the best way?), but got stuck with the syntax.  Using:

```
 ffprobe -show_streams -select_streams a format=sample_rate -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 myfile.mp3
```

Its not happy with this syntax, saying "`myfile.mp3` provided as input filename, but '`format=sample_rate`' was already specified."

Is there a better way to achieve this? If not, can someone help me with my `ffmpeg` probe syntax?

Answer (score 2):

Remove `-show_streams`, add `-loglevel error`, and change `format=sample_rate` to `-show_entries stream=sample_rate`.

```
ffprobe -loglevel error -select_streams a -show_entries stream=sample_rate -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 myfile.mp3
```